# Conditional fields on content type with paragraphs

Tags: 8, forms, paragraphs

I saw this question repeat in a few places without an adequate answer.

I have a D8 site that has a certain contain type ('deals') which contains an array of 'deal' paragraphs. 
Each 'deal' contains a 'deal_type' field and then a few content fields ('image', 'text', 'banner', etc.).

I would like to conditionally show the paragraph fields, according to what the user selected in the 'deal_type' dropdown.

I saw some answers mention a `MODULE_form_alter()` hook but this didn't seem to be called when I load my 'edit content type' page.

Can anyone help with this?

Comment: "I saw some answers mention a MODULE_form_alter() hook but this didn't seem to be called when I load my 'edit content type' page." <--- can't tell you why since you didn't show your code. Did you clear your cache after adding it?

Comment: The form_alter hook is successfully called when display a webform on a page, but I'm trying to edit an admin content menu.  The hook doesn't seem to be called for that.

Comment: See my last comment.

Comment: I did clean my cache. And the hook is called - but not for admin forms.

Comment: As I said, can't tell you why since you didn't show your code.

Comment: Didn't write any code - I am asking which code to write. Only mentioning in passing that the form_alter hook isn't called for admin content.  function mythemename_form_alter(&$form, FormStateInterface $form_state, $form_id)
{
  $test = 4;
}

Comment: hook_form_alter() is called on all forms, admin or otherwise. If you put it in your main theme's .theme file however, and you are using a separate admin theme, it will not be called. That's a random stab in the dark though.

Comment: Thanks, I'll see if I can get it to work.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes you will have to hook form alter.
Make sure that you have done the following to make sure it's working.
1- create a module say it's called deals
2- add the deals_form_alter(...add the default params here ) In the deals.module file.
3- clear the cache 
4- add your edit form is in an if condition then right the following logic. (You can get the form is by dumping the $form['#id'].
5- use the states functionality or Ajax callback to hide and show the fields you want.

https://www.drupal.org/docs/8/api/form-api/conditional-form-fields
And https://www.drupal.org/docs/8/api/javascript-api/ajax-forms